# Fixed div on image with responsive design

Tags: css, image, html, position

So, I have the following problem. I have an img that is let's say a flag and i have also an circle that i want to be shown on the bottom left/ or right corner. I position it easly but the problem is that the site is responsive and the image is getting smaller if we resize the page and also the circle is not anymore in the left corner when the image is resized.

this is my html:

```
<div class="flag-left">
    <img src="images/flags/adelaide.png" alt="picture" />
    <div class="circle-left"><p>11</p></div>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
#main-content .team-info .flags {

width: 30%;
height: 57px;
line-height: 57px;
vertical-align: middle;
}

#main-content .team-info .flags .flag-left {
position:
relative;
width: 40%;
float: left;
}

#main-content .team-info .flags img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}

.circle-left {
position: relative;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: #000;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
color: #fff;
bottom: 18px;
left: 27px;
}

.circle-left p { position: absolute; line-height: 0px; left: 6px; }
```

Thanks in advice :)

EDIT: I forgot my image style and i added jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BSaYZ/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
#main-content .team-info .flags .flag-left {
    position:relative;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}

#main-content .team-info .flags .flag-left img{
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto
}

.circle-left {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    bottom: 18px;
    left: 27px;
}

.circle-left p{
    line-height: 0px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Yes I forgot to add the img styling. Its the same here but the circle is still not on the fixed bottom left corner of the image on the smaller screens

Comment: i have added jsfiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your .flag-left to have a display: block;

Like this

```
#main-content .team-info .flags .flag-left { position: relative; width: 40%; float: left; display: block;}
```

The circle will then stay inside the div. I have found that whenever you have a container div and within that you want something positioned absolute within the container, you should always give the container div a block display.